# How to test with jasmine a post call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to test a function with jasmine on javascript but i'm having a problem I haven't found any information to test a $.post or $.get function, also, because i'm using the done ($.deferred) which is asynchronous don't know how to handle it. The code is the following

```
function registrarUsuario(cel, eMail, nombre){
$.post(url, {
       phone_number : cel,
       email : eMail,
       name : nombre
       }).done(exitoso(data))}
```

The question is, how do I test a $.post or $.get function with jasmine, and using the done function of the jqXHR.

The function exitoso(data) is the following:

```
function exitoso(data){
navigator.notification.alert('User register',
                             alertDismmissed(nombre, eMail, cel),
                             'Sucess');}
```

---

The reason I was having an error with data ErrorReference, but I had to change the code $.post(...).done as follow

```
.done(function(data){
 exitoso(data);
}
```

or also could have work as:
    .done(
      exitoso
     );

Thanks to Andreas Köberle for answering.

Answer (score 3):

So you can spy on `$.post` and return a resolved deferred:

```
var dfr = new $.Deferred();
dfr.resolve({data: "data"})
jasmine.spyOn($, 'post').andReturn(dfr)
registrarUsuario()
```

Another solution is to use sinonJs' [fakeServer](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer):

```
this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
this.server.respondWith('{data: "data"}');
server.autoRespond = true;
registrarUsuario()
```

Comment: Using jasmine it shows this: "error ReferenceError: data is not defined", do you know what can be done? maybe using callFake, I've tried using spyOn('data') and other stuff so that the variable is not taken as null.

Comment: You should spy on `exitoso` to check that it was called with `exitoso`. Maybe you post more of your code, its hard to guess what `exitoso` is and how to spy on it with your example.

Comment: Andreas thanks for your time, I added all the code i'm using. I know that exitoso is not being called because it get stuck on data referenceError

Comment: I'm sorry, I found the mistake, i'm going to correct my question, thanks by the way I gave you the point! it was because the way the function was being called.

Comment: Ah ok, the problem is that you call `done(exitoso(data))`, I think what really wanna to is to execute the function `exitoso` on the success of your ajax call: `done(exitoso)`